# PHPMailer AddStringAttachment with PDF

Tags: php, pdf, phpmailer, email-attachments

I am new to phpmailer and I am able to send emails, emails with attachments, and stringattachments that are .txt files however I cannot send stringattachments with PDF's. The email is sent, but the PDF is corrupted/unable to open. Can anyone help to send the AddStringAttachment with the attachment being a PDF rather than a .txt? Thanks

```
<?php

require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer();

$body2 = "You are receiving this email because the Transfer Application submitted for $Name transferring to $Receiving is missing required documentation. 
Please see the note below for details. The transfer application will not be reviewed until all of the necessary materials are received by the UHSAA.

    <p> Details:
        $Notes ";

$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->AddAddress($emailp);
$mail->AddCC('transfers@uhsaa.org');
$mail->AddStringAttachment($body2, 'Filename.pdf', 'base64', 'application/octet-stream');

$mail->Subject = "Test";
$body = ("See attachment");
$mail->MsgHTML($body);
$mail->AddAddress($address);
$mail->AddCC($address);
if(!$mail->Send())

;
?>
```

Again, if I just change Filename.pdf to Filename.txt everything works so I'm assuming the problem is with the encoding but I can't figure it out. Please help so I can send stringattachment PDF's. Thanks.

Comment: "application/octet-stream", *.pdf.  No its not,  its a string of text, calling it a pdf does not magically make it one.

Comment: I tried 'application/pdf' but that gave me the same error when trying to open the emailed pdf as the 'application/octet-stream'.

Comment: its not a pdf, never will be a pdf its a string of text.

Comment: what  you got ? pls explain the solution

Answer (score 18):

No need to chunk_split base64encode the pdf string just do

```
$mail->addStringAttachment($pdfString, 'vouchers.pdf');
```

Answer (score 10):

Try

```
$mail->AddStringAttachment($body2, 'Filename.pdf', 'base64', 'application/pdf');
```

it will work

Comment: No need to specify encoding and MIME type - both will be set automatically.

Answer (score 5):

This worked fine for me:

`$mail->addStringAttachment(base64_decode($attachmentBase64), $filename);`